# What is a good, simple way to model wave amplitudes with transmission through different media?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I want a simple model to describe the electric field that we detect at a receiver position when some object is close to the optical axis. To make the model more simple, we treat our waves as rays to first order.

The set-up is as follows. We have a transmitter and a receiver antenna which are placed opposite of each other. Somewhere in between, but close enough to the optical axis to play some role, there is an object. For simplicity, we will assume this object to be a circle of homogenous properties (importantly, attenuation coefficient and refraction index, also we assume no reflection) and we restrict ourselves to a 2D description. The transmitter sends out a radial electric wave and we know the free-space solution to be
\begin{equation}
E(r) = \frac{A_0}{r} \times \exp(-ikr),
\end{equation}
where $A_0$ is a constant, $r$ is the distance between transmitter and receiver antenna and $k$ is the wavenumber, which we can also express as $\omega/c * n$, with $\omega$ the circular frequency of the wave, $c$ the speed of light in a vacuum and $n$ the refractive index of the medium.

I assume that this describes the first arrival signal at my receiver. (The object is close to, but not on the optical axis, therefore it does not obstruct this ray.) However, we should also pick up a second signal of waves that enter the object and arrive with some delay (due to their longer physical travel length and their lowered speed in the object). Currently, I model this as a ray bundle sent from the transmitter to the circle, which then gets refracted according to Snellius' law upon entering the circle. Then I determine their exit positions. These exit positions I treat as basically point sources which emit radial waves. Then I sum up all of these new radial waves at the receiver position. In other words, the model for a refracted ray with index $j$ is:
\begin{equation}
E^{\text{refr}}_j = \frac{A_0}{r_{1,j} + r_{2,j} + r_{3,j}} \times \exp(-i k r_{1,j} - i k r_{3,j} - i k_m r_{2,j} - \mu r_{2,j})
\end{equation}
$r_1$ describes the distance from transmitter to the point of entry into the circle, $r_2$ the distance between the points of entry and exit into and from the circle and $r_3$ the distance from the exit point to the receiver. $k_m$ is the wave number inside of the material and $\mu$ is the attenuation coefficient of the material. Therefore, the total refracted field is the sum over the individual contributions, i.e.
\begin{equation}
E^{\text{refr}} = \sum_j E^{\text{refr}}_j
\end{equation}
And the final field would then be the sum of direct and refracted field:
\begin{equation}
E^{\text{total}} = E^{\text{refr}} + E(r)
\end{equation}
However, it is easy to see that this description absolutely overstates the importance of the refracted field. Simply due to the fact that we sum over hundreds to thousands of vectors for the refracted field while we only have one contribution for the direct ray, this completely dominates the signal. I thought about weighting the refracted field by dividing through the number of vectors we used for the modelling, but even then we would end up with roughly a 50-50 contribution (if $r \approx r_1 + r_2 + r_3$), which intuitively seems wrong to me.

How can I properly model the amplitude?